# How to properly build keycloak from source code

Tags: java, git, maven, keycloak

I need to build a custom version of Keycloak in order to perform another action when password reset happens. 
In order to do this, I followed the steps described in the Readme file on the git repository:

1. Check java version, maven version, git version (openjdk 11, amazon corretto, maven 3.6.3)
2. Run "git clone https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak.git"
3. Switch to the newly created directory
4. Run "mvn install"

Some tests failed in module keycloak-saml-core:

```
org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.SAMLParserTest
[ERROR] testSaml20AuthnResponseNonAsciiNameDefaultLatin2(org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.SAMLParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< ERROR!
ParsingException [location=null]org.keycloak.saml.common.exceptions.ParsingException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[9,91]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.DefaultPicketLinkLogger.parserException(DefaultPicketLinkLogger.java:420)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.util.StaxParserUtil.getElementText(StaxParserUtil.java:492)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.util.SAMLParserUtil.parseNameIDType(SAMLParserUtil.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.assertion.SAMLSubjectParser.processSubElement(SAMLSubjectParser.java:58)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.assertion.SAMLSubjectParser.processSubElement(SAMLSubjectParser.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.parsers.AbstractStaxParser.parse(AbstractStaxParser.java:97)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.assertion.SAMLAssertionParser.processSubElement(SAMLAssertionParser.java:69)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.assertion.SAMLAssertionParser.processSubElement(SAMLAssertionParser.java:34)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.parsers.AbstractStaxParser.parse(AbstractStaxParser.java:97)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.protocol.SAMLResponseParser.processSubElement(SAMLResponseParser.java:77)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.protocol.SAMLResponseParser.processSubElement(SAMLResponseParser.java:38)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.parsers.AbstractStaxParser.parse(AbstractStaxParser.java:97)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.SAMLParser.parse(SAMLParser.java:123)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.parsers.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:98)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.parsers.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:102)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.api.saml.v2.response.SAML2Response.getSAML2ObjectFromStream(SAML2Response.java:389)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.SAMLParserTest.assertParsed(SAMLParserTest.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.saml.processing.core.parsers.saml.SAMLParserTest.testSaml20AuthnResponseNonAsciiNameDefaultLatin2(SAMLParserTest.java:262)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[9,91]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:902)
    at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:187)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.util.EventReaderDelegate.getElementText(EventReaderDelegate.java:110)
    at org.keycloak.saml.common.util.StaxParserUtil.getElementText(StaxParserUtil.java:490)
    ... 44 more
```

After this, I tried running the project directly from Intellij, but received the following error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/adapters/tomcat/KeycloakAuthenticatorValve
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.SpringBootAdapterApplication.main(SpringBootAdapterApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/adapters/tomcat/KeycloakAuthenticatorValve
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:201) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:136) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/adapters/tomcat/KeycloakAuthenticatorValve
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration$1.customize(KeycloakAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1622) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried skipping the tests with `mvn install -DskipTests` and the build succeeded, but I am not aware of the location of the newly created jar file containing the result of the build.
Also, changing java version from 11 to 8 did not seem to affect the errors that would occur.
Switching to a fresh linux virtual machine did not really affect things, but tests would still fail for some unknown/unspecified reason, but in the test suites, not in the saml package.

Please note that this is the version as-is from the repository, with no changes done by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably maven profile is missing.

Documentation: [Building from source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/docs/building.md)

1. You need Java JDK8 and Maven installed and configured;
2. In temrinal, change direcotry to project's root;
3. Run maven command:

`mvn -Pdistribution -pl distribution/server-dist -am -Dmaven.test.skip clean install`

Resulting release distribution will be in `./distribution/server-dist/target/`

Comment: Thank you! This maven command seemed to work, I found a working archive with keycloak in the server-dist/target directory. There is still an error message, though, but everything seems fine regardless ```OS=Windows and the assembly descriptor contains a *nix-specific root-relative-reference (starting with slash) /```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in test and by skipping test will move you forward (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/docs/building.md). However there is clearly an issue with test file probably with encoding that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a maven command that reliably solves this issue for me:

```
mvn clean install -Pdistribution -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the entrance in testsuite folder  keycloakserver class
2. and idea add  a jboss(wildfly） server
3. config as jar debug
4. debug

url in chinese blog by me
https://blog.csdn.net/xiaohelong2005/article/details/118932623

I hope this will help you a lot
note:mvn uses golang-mvn-wrapper which visit the google server ,if you behind gfw or other firewall block the google service,you need proxy
the tool v2ray and proxifier need to be used.

Comment: in idea add Application config, and the shorten command line choose jar manifest

Comment: in idea compile all module jdk version need to set to the same as required,for me set to 1.8

Comment: source debug  chinese url blog https://blog.csdn.net/xiaohelong2005/article/details/118998943?spm=1001.2014.3001.5501